# how to add string to a list inside a for loop using javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to add all node names to a list if they do not already exist in the list.

I know my if statement is incorrect here, but not sure exactly what is wrong.

```
nodeList = []

var data = [
    {
    "something": "something",
    "stages": [{
                "node": {"name": "test0"},
                "status": {"name": "test"},
                "time": {"name": "test"}
               },{
                "node": {"name": "test1"},
                "status": {"name": "test"},
                "time": {"name": "test"}
               }]
     }
];

data.forEach(obj =>
  obj.stages.forEach(stage => if (nodeList.indexOf(stage.node.name) > -1) {
  nodeList.push({stage.node.name})
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few syntax errors and you need to test:

```
if (nodeList.indexOf(stage.node.name) < 0)
```

not `> -1`. You want to add the value when it's not there, which means `indexOf` will return `-1`. I think this is what you're after:

```js
nodeList = []

var data = [
    {
    "something": "something",
    "stages": [{
                "node": {"name": "test0"},
                "status": {"name": "test"},
                "time": {"name": "test"}
               },{
                "node": {"name": "test1"},
                "status": {"name": "test"},
                "time": {"name": "test"}
               }]
     }
];

data.forEach(obj =>
  obj.stages.forEach(stage => {
    if (nodeList.indexOf(stage.node.name) < 0) {
      nodeList.push(stage.node.name)
    }
  }))

  console.log(nodeList)
```

If you can use ES6 things would be easier — you could use a Set and avoid the test altogether:

```
nodeList = new Set

data.forEach(obj =>
  obj.stages.forEach(stage => nodeList.add(stage.node.name)
))
```

Then you could iterate the Set or spread it into an array depending on what you're doing next.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.indexOf(element)` returns `-1` if `element` wasn't found.

In your case, you are using `> -1` which is the contrary.

There is an updated version of your code:

```js
var nodeList = []

var data = [{
  "something": "something",
  "stages": [{
    "node": {"name": "test0"},
    "status": {"name": "test"},
    "time": {"name": "test"}
   }, {
    "node": {"name": "test1"},
    "status": {"name": "test"},
    "time": {"name": "test"}
  }]
}];

data.forEach((obj) => {
  obj.stages.forEach((stage) => {
    if (nodeList.indexOf(stage.node.name) === -1) {
      nodeList.push(stage.node.name);
    }
  });
});

console.log(nodeList);
```